# STDOUT logs not working when using symlink for log file to /proc/1/fd/1 on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cron, stdout

I have a cronjob that runs every minute which will redirect output to a log file `/var/log/cronjob/cron.log`. Since this is running in Kubernetes, I want to redirect the log to STDOUT.

The approach I took was to use a symlink using `RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/cronjob/cron.log`:

```
# ls -la /var/log/cronjob/cron.log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jan 21 19:23 /var/log/cronjob/cron.log -> /proc/1/fd/1
```

When I run `kubectl logs` it has no output.

If I (within the container), delete the symlink and create as a normal file, my output as expected appears in the `/var/log/cronjob/cron.log` file.

```
# tail -f /var/log/cronjob/cron.log
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.3' 'artisan' sync:health_check > '/dev/null' 2>&1
Running scheduled command: ('/usr/bin/php7.3' 'artisan' compute:user_preferences > '/dev/null' 2>&1 ; '/usr/bin/php7.3' 'artisan' schedule:finish "framework/schedule-9019c9dc22ad7439efd038277fe8f370f56958e7") > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &
```

**How can I get the my log via symlink write to STDOUT?**

I have tried other things such as:

- Use `/dev/stdout` for the symlink
- Tail the `/var/log/cronjob/cron.log` file within the entrypoint

**Edit: More information about files/scripts:**

crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/schedule-run.sh
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file
```

/usr/local/bin/schedule-run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source container environment variables
source /tmp/export

# Run Laravel scheduler
php /var/www/api/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cronjob/cron.log 2>&1
```

**Edit #2:**

Currently my `CMD` looks like this which spawns multiple child processes:

```
CMD export >> /tmp/export && crontab /etc/cron.d/realty-cron && cron && tail -f /var/log/cronjob/cron.log
```

```
root@workspace-dev-condos-ca-765dc6686-h8vdl:/var/www/api# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c export >> /tmp/export && crontab /etc/cron.d/realty-cron && cron && tail -f /var/log/cronjob/cron.log
root         8     1  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 cron
root         9     1  0 21:55 ?        00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/cronjob/cron.log
root       170     1  0 21:59 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -s
root       233     0  0 22:00 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root       249     1  0 22:00 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -s
root      1277   233  0 22:26 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

I'm not sure if that is relevant but through trial and error testing, I noticed that sometimes `echo "test1" >> /proc/1/fd/1` or `echo "test2" >> /proc/1/fd/2` will output to stdout (`kubectl logs`) but not both at the same time. I feel like the child processes are related but don't know why.

Comment: Try `tail -F <file>` and see if it works. Although I think it's supposed to work as is.

Comment: Just to use a capital `-F`? I could try that but don't think that will fix it. The small `-f` works on my docker environments just not the K8 ones.

Comment: Is it possible for me to pull this image so I can try it on my cluster? And what version of kubernetes are you using?

Comment: @HelloWorld, I appreciate the effort however we pack our source code into there which I cannot share. The cluster version is 1.14 (EKS).

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile?